# Adding custom naming rule to StyleCop

Tags: stylecop

I have seen [Configuring StyleCop Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md) and also [this guide](https://blog.submain.com/stylecop-detailed-guide/).

What I want is to add the following custom StyleCop Rule:

**protected variables should start with an underscore**

Is this possible to add this rule using StyleCop.json?

Comment: Hi have you got any solution for custom rule set ?

Comment: I haven't found any solution

Comment: Only one way we can do os edit stylecop source code and build it. But it will be very time consuming..